# Tilloston Equation of State to determine the temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

Given a hyper-velocity impact and the [Tilloston Equation of State](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/278653/1-s2.0-S1877705813X00098/1-s2.0-S1877705813009594/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBAaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIDsu6zObJsXr5tJP6zDstECxiRTbBKSg2rL2Jm6HzoYnAiEAmW7m9ESWKG5ketq8ku%2FmNyjlJwgo8BaOy1%2BsHOPqqjUqsQUIGBAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDCMUE2JKtIunqMPZTiqOBW5xyXe5IEKmycz3ohxpLvWHOrJvVsNw9e1dQ38DhB9oOi6dYqz5JZMFZF1PkJqrns3rQ9qgydT1kyXFvWkzLGPiqW3Jr9UQ0lvbbYDFSJVD4vYmSbTNSMZN9zJcdWRgN9rQyaJARfk6EM3KuXbaa6mN2%2B3tZ0FP1y6GpJkZre5VjMswueAIZQt1nZUMjuYnxak0YgqEMidBb8t704UauLmXokXxsVct8Gi5UgSotl611UzwWlVxnnFhccov6AH%2FgMsAPaWpYgNjybRVTucEPfSW7sHqjobTVGuFlf%2BQpAcZ26MOCTZjgcBz2hI9O8wBCRxlNKgIk7WzhCQDyDn4gj%2FJPkU1s7XuLUdMJ8TN0cvY2QUbPO0uzRFJnJSTNk0cYO%2FoNzw6n0eRjjQyH02cUv%2B19wKDcQEYQ4Q64mG0gqjEAP3qIdjaPxsYwzvCOawKVpBPiOmm46gyxxEFdD8tJk3LcwT33wmbgyU883gfVH5BPeYQRX4qQK3SyNP%2BeP8L1vmkEGN2a0s4zISGAAGa7aeF5fEM1Cb42qd5WyJTm2Jtmz22Wf1NgFjJw7F5PrBmQNx9g2qvbTVxO27iX8965Oj3vlrOc4CYmCA7sXoEv57KaaGptXEPVHebOXHv2ZPsk60acooMv2xatk9ijjdcUfdx3UEiB6i3oZ%2B3g%2BY5BU96oC9c%2B5YNlq75kD9SBfO8%2FXvVi7zQICU07N0iAX0Xhvz3tjas81oqKWN5lz4TwVkn77DXGO6SSM%2Bay%2Baxjw3mWxGfoIENJ58uC49NrFsK95EbdyGvUNAH06zQv37MKfzlcPKlgpwLLxqf5TdiE2u%2FX%2FV6eJp2C0Jy2QuMS2uvIHeCYIcI%2FembafaCd8gtezDXu%2BuoBjqxAWrG0b5bEwbfExKiL6C%2BMZIArfmChJTyJDx695%2Fb5K33Ubu6aYolkKeF3ZSUGp6oBB2xy%2BeCclAkgJeCkFqt7pNJH4eRhOKsbxADRAf6v5yISFFskvWOl8R7kM5ZSE64RJ7wwm1YYBJpENZgDMdMwWn5X2JpgxTJIC%2FGh3PIns5suh9iVieekuPyTOsAr7maKgrIvH6QK64DqxCKOlXQAOflKOOBubznB7%2F0qcNBvAnZZw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231002T161846Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYSUEV474P%2F20231002%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=5ca7cb3191c651f38bed13ea04184a6fecf96ac6e36c7a78deb381487d8dd128&hash=8b72c1e93f2b98b05325c6c3694d5fc91b4c970a63efdb205deac34fccb4dd62&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S1877705813009594&tid=spdf-507fcac1-4521-4519-b5d5-78150e34a156&sid=2a9f308623b65347645b73d62b55708969bfgxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=1308595e01005550530a05&rr=80fe435dbc8b8ae7&cc=in) (Sec. 2.1), how do I determine the temperature? I suppose we use the internal energy E to find the temperature for a given EOS, but I wanted to know how exactly.